# Can I build tool storage cabinets off of bottom of deck joists?

Tags: deck, woodworking, joists, cabinets

I have room, and would like to make, some storage for tools in an area under my deck using 3/4 in plywood.  I could cement in 4x4 or something in the ground and build off of that but behind a retaining wall is probably lots of 1' stone (not sure how deep) and I'm not sure how secure it would be and i think a better idea would to just hang the cabinets from the joists.  This is really only to hold lots of tool bags and some chemicals like pesticides and weed control. The deck will be waterproof above, and Ill have some area underneath to store hoses and small things. Is there any problems with this?  Any suggestions?

(More info: I don't mind getting on a step stool if I need to reach far back, and I want to be able to partially disassemble if I need to get behind to work/inspect deck, gutters behind or clean behind. I'm planning on mounting 3/4 top along with sides of cabinets using pocket screws.  I plan on putting a 2x4 to hold the back wall and using a locking shelf support pegs to keep it in place.  I plan on putting the horizontal shelves using shelf standards and cabinet doors held with piano hinges.)

[image: Messy area I want to build storage]
[image: Front view of partial-plan]
[image: Back view of partial-plan]

Comment: No problem unless you start hanging cars or trucks up there.  Joists been used to hold shelves and hangers since beginning of time.  Just make sure that any wood that can get wet has plenty of air movement to dry out or is protected(treated,stain/paint)

Comment: "the deck will be waterproof above" until it isn't. Plan on building out of pressure treated materials and expect your tools to be wet (or at least damp), so plan on appropriate water protection for each of them. TBH, though, your picture shows a pretty dry space. Does it stay that dry during a heavy rainstorm?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FreeMan .  Yes, I was definitely only going to use exterior-rated plywood (which according to my research is bonded with 100 percent waterproof adhesive).  If you have a better material you would suggest please let me know.  It is waterproof above using a spline between deckboards and should have gutters around the deck. So it should be waterproof even in heavy rains. But like you said, you never know about the future, so I'm going to overbuild it.

Comment: @crip659 feel free to answer this question so I can accept it and give you the rep if you want.

Comment: @Joe  A good answer would depend on more information, but as long as you don't place too much weight on one joist(no engines), a few tools and supplies spread out over multiple joists(to hold shelve hangers)  are usually okay.

Comment: AIUI, exterior grade ply is waterproof glues, while PT _also_ treats the lumber to reduce the chance that the wood itself will rot (leaving behind perfectly preserved glue).